# How to print with end=" " immediately in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.3

How can I use print statement without newline and execute this immediately?

Because this:

```
print("first", end=" ")
time.sleep(5)
print("second")
```

will print after 5 sec both:

```
first second
```

But I want to write 'first', wait for five seconds, and then write 'second'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush `stdout`:

```
print("first", end=" ", flush=True)
```

`stdout` is line buffered, which means the buffer is flushed to your screen every time you print a newline. If you are not printing a newline, you need to flush manually.

For anyone *not* yet using Python 3.3 or newer, the `flush` keyword argument is new in 3.3. For earlier versions you can flush `stdout` explicitly:

```
import sys

print("first", end=" ")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it as follows as well:

```
import sys, time

sys.stdout.write("First ")
time.sleep(5)
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write("Second\n")
```

Comment: `sys.stdout` in Python 3 can still be line buffered and you'd still need to flush explicitly. You forgot to include a newline in the second `write()` call.

Comment: Did you mean a newline before or after the string `second`?

Comment: `print()` adds an extra `sys.stdout.write('\n')` unless `end` is set to something else. So, when using `print('Second')` you get two writes; `sys.stdout.write('Second')` and `sys.stdout.write('\n')`.

Comment: Do you mean like that? `"Second\n"`

Comment: Yes, I mean like that.

Comment: There are two problems still here: you didn't import `time` and  `time.sleep()` takes an argument, and you didn't flush `sys.stdout` still. **Without the flush this doesn't solve the problem**.